# How to log in using python requests and selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, request, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to log into a site using python with requests libary but the next button works with javascript and I cant interract it with html, I searched that I should use selenium then I searched about it but I couldnt find a explanation about integrating or using them with same cookie.I tried integrated libaries but they still havent got a tutorial. what should I do?

Comment: what you mean by `using them with same cookie`?

Comment: @Jeril yes, first it will go into login page and enter credentials with requests then click the javascript button with selenium

Comment: even i tried that once, but i guess the UI works differently. so need to work using selenium

Comment: Use `session` for persistent session https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects

Answer (score 0):

Use [Session](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) for persistent session across different requests.

**Example**

Let’s persist some cookies across requests:

```
s = requests.Session()

s.get('https://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789')
r = s.get('https://httpbin.org/cookies')

print(r.text)
# '{"cookies": {"sessioncookie": "123456789"}}'
```